# Exception Handling and Logging: Better Practice

Tags: java, logging, exception

Code ( Java ) snippet

```
.....
.....
 if ( response.check() == checkNumber )
 { 
        String message = "You are looking at Wrong Place";
        logger.log( message );
        throw new UserAtWrongPlaceException( message ); 
        /* stops here */
 }
 .....
 ...
 if ( response.check() == somethingElse)
 {
 ......
 }
```

I have code to check for response and if the response is equal to defined constatnt checkNumber, i would like to log message and throw exception but by doing this my code execution will be stopped at this point instead of proceeding further.

What would be the better way to log my message, throw UserAtWrongPlaceException and continue 
        executing rest of the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an exception in Java always stops the execution of that method. It returns to whatever piece of code called the method with the exception. If that code catches the exception, it goes to the catch block, otherwise, it throws the exception further upwards.

Perhaps you were looking for a way to attach the exception to your log? Loggers have a method for that:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO,message,new UserAtWrongPlaceException(message));
```

Of course, you could throw a random exception, but if you want the method to continue, you'd have to catch it:

```
try {
    if(response.check() == checkNumber) {
        String message = "You are looking at Wrong Place";
        logger.log(message);
        throw new UserAtWrongPlaceException(message);
    }
} catch(UserAtWrongPlaceException e) {
    //Do something with the exception, or just ignore it.
}
```

But then, of course, you might as well just NOT throw the exception, because the result will be the same and instantiating the exception only slows it down.

Perhaps you were looking for a way to continue with the method but have the exception thrown at the end rather than returning successfully. For such practice I'd store the exception for later (though admittedly quite convoluted). Like this:

```
UserAtWrongPlaceException exception = null;
if(response.check() == checkNumber) {
    String message = "You are looking at Wrong Place";
    logger.log(message);
    exception = new UserAtWrongPlaceException(message);
}
...
if(response.check() == somethingElse) { ... }
...
if(exception != null) {
    throw exception;
}
return true;
```

If you choose that pattern, though, you'll have to take a look at what happens if multiple of these ifs throw an exception. In the code snippet above, this will result in all exceptions being logged but only the last being thrown.

Remember, a method can either return, or throw an exception. It can't do both and it can't throw multiple exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out the stack trace but not halt the execution you could use:

```
new UserAtWrongPlaceException( message ).printStackTrace();
```